# Adding new Columns in Tablerow Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to ask a user the x and y coordinate of a given Table. The selected cell is then filled with Input. Now I want to add a feature which creates a new row and columns at the bottom if the given x/y coordinate exceeds the given table. I managed to make the insert a row function work, but how can I add the columns to this row?

```
  <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {

let button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let xObj = document.getElementById("field_x");
    let yObj = document.getElementById("field_y");
    let textObj = document.getElementById("text");

    let x = xObj.value;
    let y = yObj.value;
    let text = textObj.value;
    let fillxy = String(x+y);
    console.log(y);
    var table = document.getElementById("gametable");
    var xcounter = x;
    var ycounter = y;
    for (let i = 4; i < xcounter; i += 1) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        let newrow = gametable.appendChild(row);
        for (let j = 0; j < y; j+= 1) {
            let cell = document.createElement('td');

        }

    }

    let tabletofill = document.getElementById(fillxy);
    tabletofill.innerText = [text];

    tabletofill.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(tabletofill.innerText != "") {
            tabletofill.innerText = "";
        }
    })

});
```

});

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show the code you have which is working and the code which is not working, and describe any errors, etc

Comment: adding the new row works but how can I adress this new row and add the columns? if I do gametable.appendChild(cell), its adding a new cell but not in the new row

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a cell in each row, at the same position :

**JS :**

```
function addColumn(colIndex) {

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var rows = table.rows;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        var cellsNumber = rows[i].cells.length;
        if (colIndex <= cellsNumber) {
            rows[i].insertCell(colIndex);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error : index out of range');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/tsgmgyc1/2/**